# Cannot use defined javascript variable inside jquery's .html

Tags: javascript, jquery, variables

I kind of call a variable inside of a .html(); but it does not function properly.

```
var cap2 = "Here is a muddy truck.";
id = $(this).attr("id");
$("#caption").html("cap"+id); // this literally outputs "cap2" into my caption div
```

Obviously this is not the complete code but I think its enough for someone knowledgable to point me in the right direction.

I should also note when the last line looks like this

```
$("#caption").html(cap2); // this correctly outputs "Here is a muddy truck"
```

all is well but I need the numeric slot to be dynamic. Any thoughts?

Comment: Post more of the code; both HTML and JavaScript. So that we can help troubleshoot.

Comment: I would like to know what $(this) is referring to?

Comment: There are better ways to do this, like not using just a number for an ID, and if you have multiple strings, putting them in an array and referencing an array value instead of trying to eval a bunch of different variablenames etc.

Comment: More code probably isn't needed. $(this) is likely referring to an element accessed through jQuery and isn't relevant other than that he is getting its ID attribute.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If your `cap2` variable is declared globally, you can use:

```
$("#caption").html(window["cap"+id]);
```

Comment: I ended up using this solution. This solution only worked after declaring my capX variables outside of my $(document).ready function. Thank you works as I needed.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use the 'evil' eval function:

```
$("#caption").html(eval("cap"+id));
```

Evil because it can do all sort of dangerous things!

Comment: If the OP has complete control over the value of `id` then this should be safe enough. But if there is any possibility of user entered data coming in the `id` part, avoid `eval`

Answer (score 0):

In javascript '+' is used to concatenate strings, and since the function receives on string parameter, you are sending it "cap2" as a string, and not the variable.
The `eval()` method will take the string you give it and run it as if it was code, hence, sending the 'cap2' variable to the `.html()` method.

```
$("#caption").html(eval("cap"+id));
```

Answer (score 0):

The javascript function `eval` takes a string a evaluates it as a javascript variable, function, etc. Use `.html(eval("cap"+id));`

Answer (score 0):

Just an example of how stuff like this would normally be handled:

```
<a href="#" id="a0"></a>
<a href="#" id="a1"></a>
<a href="#" id="a2"></a>
<a href="#" id="a3"></a>
```

---

```
$('a').on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var caps = [
                "Here is a muddy truck.",
                "Here is a strange duck",
                "Here is the proper code",
                "Here's Johnny"
                ],
         id = this.id.replace('a','');

    $("#caption").html(caps[id]);
});
```

Preferrably declaring the array outside the click function, but it's just an example!

Answer (score 0):

Adeneo's comment is probably the most helpful until now. If you have to reference variables with different numbers, make an array in the right order and call the index:

```
var caption = $('#caption'), // no use writing a variable on each action
    caps = [
        "Here is a muddy truck.",
        "another caption"
    ]; // fill with your captions

$(document).on('click', 'a', function() {
    caption.html(caps[this.id]);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not just stick your strings into a hash?  That way you don't have to do any arithmetic on the id.